# Google map for meteor

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, meteor, flow-router

I install "meteor add dburles:google-maps" in Meteor. I added this code to the React Component,

```
...
import { GoogleMaps } from 'meteor/dburles:google-maps';
...
export default class Location extends TrackerReact(React.Component){
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        ...
    };
    GoogleMaps.load();
}
componentDidUpdate(){
    GoogleMaps.create({
      name: 'exampleMap',
      element: document.getElementById('basic_map'),
      options: {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8136, 144.9631),
        zoom: 8
      }
    });
}
render() {
    ...
    return (
        ...
                    <div id="basic_map" style={{"width":"300px","height":"300px"}}></div>
        ...
    )
}
```

The problem here is the error "google not defined". I think it is from this line of code,

```
google.maps.LatLng(-37.8136, 144.9631),
```

Did I miss something in installation? How can I fix this?
I am using Meteor, ReactJs, Flow router and TrackerReact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because google hasn't been loaded yet. Make sure to check `GoogleMaps.loaded()` before you hit create.

The author, David Burles, wrote a nice [example using the library with react](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps-react-example/blob/master/imports/lib/GoogleMap.js), which should be helpful. It uses createContainer instead of TrackerReact but should get you on the right track.

Comment: Where will I put GoogleMaps.loaded()?

Comment: @JohnArellano Well, if I look at the TrackerReact docs, it says: "Any reactive data sources (e.g: collection.find() or Session.get('foo')) used **in your render method or by methods called by your render method are automatically reactive**!"     So I'd plug it into the an if-statement in the render method and execute `create` only if it's true.

Comment: Still having an error "google is not defined". I used if(GoogleMaps.loaded()) inside render and before return statement.

Comment: Thanks . I am done in this problem, but there is new error, Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError

Comment: I think you have to provide a key to GoogleMaps.load(), as seen [here](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps#load) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages)