# dburles meteor Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, meteor-react

I am using this Meteor package, https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps-react-example/blob/master/imports/lib/GoogleMap.js

After solving my problem in Loading GoogleMaps,
[Google map for meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256432/google-map-for-meteor)

I encountered a new error,
Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError

How can I solve this problem? When can I put my API credentials?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: Do you still need help on Meteor react google map? I just successfully implemented one by myself. Take note that it's not implemented with dburles', which I gave up on.

Comment: Can you provide the package you used? and also the answer? thanks. it will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [fullstackreact/google-maps-react](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react)

```
npm install --save google-maps-react
```

Then create a google map component.

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Map, {GoogleApiWrapper, Marker} from 'google-maps-react';

export class Container extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (!this.props.loaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    return (
        <Map google={this.props.google}
          zoom={12}
          initialCenter={{lat: this.props.lat, lng: this.props.lng}}
          style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'relative'}}>
        </Map>
    )
  }
}
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: <YOUR_KEY_HERE>
})(Container)
```

After create above Container.jsx file, import it as a component, then use it as:

```
 import Container from './Container.jsx';
  ...
 <Container lat={YOUR_LAT} lng={YOUR_LNG} />
```

This is a basic way to use the library, you can add markers, label and others. For details, kindly visit [How to Write a Google Maps React Component](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-write-a-google-maps-react-component/#the-map-container-component)